# Getting wrong result in SQL Query Search using Vb.Net to find range of dates

Tags: vb.net, mdf

> My application screenshot with all records from table *InvoiceRecords*

[image]

> My Query:

```
SELECT        ID, Operator, [Invoice Number], Date, [Voucher Type],
          IncomingOutgoing, Amount, Incriment, Discriment, Month, Year
FROM          InvoiceRecords
WHERE         (Date BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2)
```

> And I used the follwoing code run the 'Query' when clicked on [Search Button]

```
Me.InvoiceRecordsTableAdapter.FillByDateDate(Me.BIS.InvoiceRecords, DTP1.Value.ToString("yyyy MMMM dd"), DTP2.Value.ToString("yyyy MMMM dd"))
```

> I was getting successful result as follows:

**Successful Screenshot #1**
[image]

**Successful Screenshot #2**
[image]

**Successful Screenshot #3**
[image]

> Until I reached at the following error by selecting the given months on the Picture:

**Problem Screenshot #1** *- Record from 'March 01, 2017' is missing*

[image]

**Problem Screenshot #2** *- Still the same record is missing*

[image]

**Problem Screenshot #3** *- No results - All the records are missing*

[image]

**Problem Screenshot #4** *- Just changing the month from July to September suddenly gives all the record*

[image]

**Problem Screenshot #5** *- Again all records disappeared when selected 'December 2017'*

[image]

> And after changing the year from '2017' to '2018' no errors seen,
>   example:

**Example 1**
[image]

**Example 2** *- No problem even with month 'July'*
[image]

**Example 3** *- Even selecting different month doesn't give any error!*
[image]

**Example 4** *- Even all records shown by selecting month 'December' on 2016*
[image]

Comment: Please someone let me reach 10 reputation to give complete description of issue

Comment: Are the dates actually stored as dates?  If they are, the `ToString("yyyy MMMM dd")` stuff isnt needed

Comment: This is not MySQL. Please add the correct tag.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel I have edited... thnx for info

@Plutonix No, they are stored as `'nvarchar(50)'`

Comment: Well, there's your problem - if you want dates to act like dates you need to store dates.  With `MMMM` do you expect `"August"` to rank higher or lower than `"July"`?

Comment: Higher? right??

Comment: No, lower because "August" is just text and "A" < "J".  Use dates

Comment: Follow Plutonix's advice. You're sorting strings and August means nothing in a string against July. The same thing would happen if you had just numbers stored as string. then numbers 1, 2, 3, 11, 10, 20 would sort 1, 10,11,2,20,3. This is basically what's happening when you move through that date from the left-most character to the right against both of them.

Comment: Oh, yeah I thought that too but was confused in some point now after you said I thought I should recheck and yeah thats right... and I'll update soon when I would be successful in resolving the issue! thnx anyway!

Comment: If you are store the date as string information in the database format using "YYYYMMDD" then "2017 February 17" -> 20170217 which is then less than "2017 August 7" -> 20170807 when doing a string comparison in the query.

Comment: @RyanRoos Oh yeah!!! thts it!!!! thts the real issue I guess I tried this way but didn't noticed it hahahaha thnx! but plutonix is right too... its kinda similar....